# Need rename several files in bash, in a way that a "block" (not the very same string) of the file names must be excluded

Tags: bash, shell

I'm in bash and need to rename my files, excluding the beggining part of the current file names.

So let's say the files:

10_SUB14926_TViei__O_luteorosea_S18_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz     62_SUB14926_TViei__P_pachy_Zando_S75_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
10_SUB14926_TViei__O_luteorosea_S18_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz     63_SUB14926_TViei__P_chondylo_S76_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
11_SUB14926_TViei__N_boothi_S19_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz

I need to exclude the double underscores and everything before that.

Like:

10_SUB14926_TViei__O_luteorosea_S18_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz

Becomes:

O_luteorosea_S18_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz

Heeeeelp

I'm stuck with that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How it fails? SO is a professional Q/A website.   
Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to ask good questions](https://zacanger.com/blog/posts/using-stackoverflow-effectively/)

Comment: Execute `var='10_SUB14926_TViei__O_luteorosea_S18_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz'; echo "${var#*__}"` then try to solve your problem yourself and then ask a question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
for file in *.gz; do mv "$file" "${file#*__}"; done
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, and I could get the idea of doing a looping with mv.

Comment: The answer was already gave by Ed Morton in comments.